# Estoy trabajando en laravel 5.5 y quiero llenar un select con los datos de una tabla a la ual esta unida 1 a muchos

Tags: laravel-5

Estoy guardando datos en mi tabla usuarios por el método store:

```
public function store(CreateUserRequest $request)
{
    $user=new User;
    $user->first_name=$request->first_name;
    $user->last_name=$request->last_name;
    $user->email=$request->email;
    $user->password=$request->password;
    $user->save();

    return redirect("panel/user");
}
```

y quiero que los datos de mi otra tabla que esta relacionada la cual se llama "udn" muestre el nombre de las udns que están mediante un select para así a la hora de agregar un usuario pueda también elegir una udn para el, este es mi modelo de usuario

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'user';

    protected $fillable = [
        'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'profile_id', 'status_type_id', 'udn_id', 'user_type_id'
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token'
    ];

    protected $dates =["deleted_at"];

    public function Udn(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Udn', 'udn_id');
    }
}
```

y este es mi modelo de udn

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Udn extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'udn';

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'slug', 'status_type_id'
    ];

    protected $dates =["deleted_at"];

        protected function User(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\User');
    }
}
```

y lo que quiero es que en un formulario tenga un select para elegirle una udn a un usuario a la hora de agregarlo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo primero que deberías hacer es enviar como parámetro a la vista donde va a estar el formulario para crear usuarios los valores de la tabla `UDN`. Supongamos que estas llamando a la vista por el método `index` del controlador de usuarios

```
use App\Udn; #Al no encontrarte dentro del controlador de UDN debes hacer llamado del modelo

public function index()
 {
   $udn = Udn::all();
   return view('index', compact('udn')); #suponiendo que tu vista para crear un nuevo user sea index, y en el compact pasas la variable que contiene toda la información de tu tabla udn

 }
```

Luego en la vista creas un `foreach` para manejar el `array` y colocar los valores dentro del `select` de la siguiente forma:

```
<select name='udn'>
    @foreach($udn as $udn)
        <option value='{{ $udn->id }}'> {{ $udn->name }} </option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: Oye si me ayudo amigo, gracias gracias! :)

Comment: Una duda mas y si quiero que en vez del id me muestre en name de la tabla??? xfa

Comment: En el option  del select  cambia $udn->id por $udn->name

Comment: me marca este error: ya que el campo solo acepta INT, que hago?? cambio su valor:SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'Activo' for column 'statustype' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `user` (`first_name`, `last_name`, `email`, `password`, `profile`, `statustype`, `udn`, `usertype`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Oma, Guillen, guillen@gmail.com, qwertyuiop, 7, Activo, 9, 9, 2019-07-23 18:25:35, 2019-07-23 18:25:35))

Comment: Lo que pasa es que udn en tu base de datos debe ser tipo INT y estas enviando un valor tipo string, cambia en tu tabla el campo udn por varchar, eso si te recomiendo dejarlo como antes, almacenando el id y no el name, es la forma correcta de hacerlo y te será mas fácil hacer futuras consultas mas precisas.